# Is it possible to call a class (A) method inside another class(B) method each time a line has executed

Tags: java

I want to know the sequence of execution of methods. Suppose I have a class A with some methods

```
Class A{
    methodA(){
       line 1;
       line 2;
       .
       .
       .
       line n;
    }
    methodB(){
       line a;
       line b;
       .
       .
       .
       line n;
    }
}
```

Now i have a class to print messages

```
 Class B{
    printMessage(){
       System.out.println("method name and line number of callee");
    }
}
```

Now is there any way to execute `printMessage()` each time `line 1, line 2,...line n` get executed without writing `printMessage()` after each line in `methodA()` or `methodB()`.

I already know how to debug, i just want to write some utility class for my convenience. Thank you.

Comment: Not really, no. You could look into aspect-oriented programming and AspectJ, or dynamic code rewriting, but really this isn't something you want to do; and if you think you want to do it you need to rethink how you write methods.

Comment: Seems something like debugging ...

Comment: May I ask what the purpose is for printing out each line of execution?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but if we can make this possible, i think programming will be a lot easier in terms of reverse engineering.

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: I agree with @LutzHorn. This looks like [XY Problem ](http://xyproblem.info/) problem. Do you have a use case? If yes, What is it? Ask the actual problem.

Comment: I don't have any XY problem, i mentioned it clearly i just want to write a convenience class to know the sequence of execution. If we write a large application at some point we got stuck finding out what's going on in process, i just want to overcome that hazard.

Comment: @Nazim reverse engineering Java is trivial - it decompiles back to the original source code. The only thing missing are the variable names. If you need to log processing on every line to reverse engineer a Java program you may simply need to improve your core Java skills.

Comment: Thanks @BoristheSpider , i am not doing any reverse engineering, i was just wondering, the time we spent to analyze something very complex using debugger, it may be easier this way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but this is pretty complicated and it goes back to rewriting the debugger you have in eclipse (assuming your using it) and it's pretty restrictive. I made an equivalent answer in this question: [Trace java bytecode stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257504/trace-java-bytecode-stream/40262274#40262274) where the OP wanted to write each bytecode line. There are a few link that might interest you.

In your case, `Class B` will be in another program than `Class A`. So you'll have an app called "myDirtyDebugger" with classB that start your other app with classA (compiled with -g) through `jdb` with something like the `Process` class. Set a breakpoint where you want (beginning of `methodA()`) and start doing step by step in "myDirtyDebugger", printing out each lines (you can get them with the `Process` class I guess).

Making a java application that starts `jdb`, which in turns start your app, sounds terrible, and it is. `jdb` is kinda the default implementation for debbuging of the JVM TI, so you can use the JVM TI to make your own (cleaner ?) debugger. I don't recommend doing it for professional purpose without someone that has knowledge in this, but it can be an interesting exercice for the curious ones.

And I doubt that developping this will be any faster than making unit tests, using a debugger or any logging framework for your prupose.

---

EDIT:

I thought there wouldn't be an easier way to do what you wanted. So that's why I wrote the hard way to do it. But then I thought: there are code generation frameworks, maybe there are code analysis/rewriting framewrok tools too ? Well, there is: [Editing/Modifying a .java file programmatically? (not the .class file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333866/editing-modifying-a-java-file-programmatically-not-the-class-file)

The [Spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/) framework for Java allows you to search, read and modify or generate classes, methods, and expressions in your source code. So, adding a log (or a call to another class) between every expression in one of your method doesn't sound so difficult with this. There are a few [examples](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/examples.html) on their site. I didn't read thoroughly, so I can't really explain you how to do it, but it is a good start.

Comment: Thanks but i don't need such a complex approach to accomplish something like this.

Comment: @Nazim I do think so too, I edited the question with something that might be more of your interest. Honestly it is still complicated, but a lot a easier.